# Is there an English word for non-vegetable fruits?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

Is there an English word or phrase that describes the category of fruits that are not vegetables, i.e., that are sweet and mostly used as dessert? For example, apples and berries should be included, but tomatoes and bell peppers not.

In German, this is called *Obst*, in Spanish it is *fruta*. [This article](http://zathras.de/angelweb/blog-fruit-vs-obst.htm) describes the difference to the English word *fruit* quite well. But I did not find any statement if there is or has been an English word for it.

Comment: How any particular plant or plant part is classified is highly dependent on culture and context. The same chef may refer to corn (maize) as both a cereal and as a vegetable, depending on how it is used. So what is considered *fruit* will depend on whether you want a meaning that is culinary, botanical, commercial, and so on.

Comment: Are you sure you want to propagate that vague use of the word “vegetable”?  You mean fruit bodies which are sweet or sour but not savory, not woody or fibrous, and often succulent.

Answer (score 14):

It's actually the same in English. Unless you're talking to a botanist, it's a non-issue.

**Fruit** ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fruits))

> a dish, quantity, or diet of fruits *live on fruit*

See also

[Is a tomato a fruit or a vegetable?](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/is-a-tomato-a-fruit-or-a-vegetable)

> As far as cooking is concerned, some things which are strictly fruits, such as tomatoes or bean pods, may be called 'vegetables' because they are used in savoury rather than sweet cooking.

Or in the words of Miles Kington

> Knowledge is knowing that a tomato is a fruit, wisdom is not putting it in a fruit salad.

Comment: Better include cucumbers, zucchini, and pumpkins in that category too, and don't forget that [bananas are herbs](https://museumvictoria.com.au/discoverycentre/discovery-centre-news/2007-archive/is-a-banana-a-fruit-or-a-herb/).

Comment: cf. a related question: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/34984/are-there-any-culinary-fruits-that-are-not-botanically-fruits-or-accessory-fruit

Comment: ...and on Seasoned Advice https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/73396/whats-really-the-difference-between-fruit-and-vegetables/

Comment: @Palizsche Thanks, that link did actually answer my question: the term seems to be "culinary fruit" (in contrast to the biological fruit). The fact that the former is not well-defined does not explain why there is no term for it; on the contrary, without a term [this wikipedia section](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit#Botanic_fruit_and_culinary_fruit) could not have a proper heading

Comment: Technically, that's correct but nobody would say "I'm going to the store to buy some culinary fruit".

Comment: I don't think bean pods are fruits even in the botanical sense, although tomatoes and eggplants are.

Comment: "A common name for this type of fruit is a pod, although the term "pod" is also applied to a number of other fruit types, such as that of vanilla (a capsule) and of the radish (a silique)." [Legume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legume)

Comment: Of course, but if you want to explain someone that concept that exists in the German language, it gets really hard without a term.

Comment: @Yogu But English is very accommodating of loanwords, a leitmotif we can noodle on at the kaffeeklatsch over the ersatz pumpernickel my doppelgänger schlepped from the delicatessen in my cobalt rucksack. Speak it with a little *sprachgefϋhl* and no one will question it after a while.

Comment: *This is all so the wrong way around!* I still remember when “fruit” meant the culinary meaning, and using it in other ways was reserved for botanists (like my mom) talking to each other.
Then, a few years ago, suddenly there were people attacking others over how “wrong” that was, and that the tomato was actually a fruit and such. I suspect for the purpose of snobbery, to raise themselves above others.
Now, it seems we’re at the cringey point, where people actually believe that the biological meaning is the default one, even though that is rarely practical, let alone sensible in daily life

Comment: Charisma is selling it as a fruit salad called salsa.

Answer (score 5):

I think one can use the term *culinary fruit* to distinguish it from the botanical fruit term.

See, for example, [this question on cooking.se](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/73396/whats-really-the-difference-between-fruit-and-vegetables) (thanks 0xFEE1DEAD), [this question on biology.se](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/34984/are-there-any-culinary-fruits-that-are-not-botanically-fruits-or-accessory-fruit) (thanks @Palitschke) or this diagram which explains the difference between culinary and botanical terms:

[image: enter link description here]
(Taken from the [Wikipedia Fruit article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit#Botanic_fruit_and_culinary_fruit)).

Comment: And for the converse, a biological vegetable that is a culinary fruit: rhubarb.